# Apache Spark not loading runtime environment config, fails to submit job

Tags: apache-spark, configuration

My Apache Spark standalone cluster was working beautifully until suddenly I tried to run a job with `screen`. (FYI I've since removed screen and done a reboot of the machine). Basically, what has happened is the Application master has refused to load any environment configuration, leaving my `spark-submit` hanging until an eventual timeout. Here's what the AM environment page looks like:

[image: environment]

Here's how I'm submitting my Spark job:

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --class app.package.TrainNetSpark --master spark://master.cluster:7077 --deploy-mode client --driver-memory 28G --executor-memory 14G --num-executors 7 --executor-cores 8 --conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=20g --conf spark.executor.heartbeatInterval=10000000 --conf spark.network.timeout=50000000 path/to/my.jar
```

I can confirm resources are freed up on all slaves and the master node. Everything seems to be running just fine until suddenly:

```
16:57:08,010 ERROR ~ Application has been killed. Reason: All masters are unresponsive! Giving up.
16:57:08,095 ERROR ~ Error communicating with MapOutputTracker
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.tryAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1325)
...
16:57:08,099 ERROR ~ Uncaught exception in thread appclient-registration-retry-thread
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Error communicating with MapOutputTracker
    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker.askTracker(MapOutputTracker.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker.sendTracker(MapOutputTracker.scala:120)
...
16:57:08,103 ERROR ~ Uncaught exception in thread Thread[appclient-registration-retry-thread,5,main]
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exiting due to error from cluster scheduler: All masters are unresponsive! Giving up.
```

My `spark-defaults.conf` looks like this:

```
spark.master spark://master.cluster:7077
spark.driver.memory 30g
spark.driver.cores 4
spark.driver.maxResultSize 20g
spark.executor.extraLibraryPath /usr/lib

spark.driver.port 7001 
spark.fileserver.port 7002 
spark.broadcast.port 7003 
spark.replClassServer.port 7004 
spark.blockManager.port 7005 
spark.executor.port 7006

spark.broadcast.factory org.apache.spark.broadcast.HttpBroadcastFactory
spark.serializer org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
```

I can confirm I've changed nothing in my application. The only difference was that I attempt to run a job inside `screen` when the behavior started. I've since removed screen and hard restarted my master and restarted the worker daemons.

It would appear the core problem is that the application master is not successfully loading runtime information. How can I fix this? Thanks!

### Update

I've narrowed the problem to (strangely) my `spark-submit` function. If I remove all parameters except the master, the application will continue as expected. What's wrong with my submit command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the problem my resetting all of my environment variables and doing the following:

I added `SPARK_HOME`, `SPARK_MASTER_IP`, `SPARK_MASTER_PORT`, and `SPARK_CONF_DIR` to my `bash_profile`. Then I added all configuration variables from the original `spark-submit` command to `spark-defaults.conf`. Restarted the master. Finally, I used a clean `spark-submit` as follows:

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --class my.package.TrainNetSpark --master spark://master.cluster:7077 path/to/my.jar
```

I logged out, logged back in, and it worked again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use class property as last argument of your command.

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --master spark://master.cluster:7077 --deploy-mode client --driver-memory 28G --executor-memory 14G --num-executors 7 --executor-cores 8 --conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=20g --conf spark.executor.heartbeatInterval=10000000 --conf spark.network.timeout=50000000  --class app.package.TrainNetSpark path/to/my.jar
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work this time, though I came back to the problem after resetting all of my environment variables and found a different solution. Going to update with an answer.